# Ionic 5 capacitor android project not sync

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic5

Android studio keeps building and install the first android project into the device.

I have tried

```
npx cap sync

npx cap copy android
```

Even delete the /android folder and add it again. The project still remains as the first time I added into the android studio. I have tried 'Gradle sync' and 'Invalidate cache /restart' still no luck.

I have update my project resource icon and splash to a customized one, but the android project still using the capacitor default icon and splash. Have anyone face this issue before?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution!

I notice the `npx sync` is copying data from the `www` folder. Thus, I think I need to update the `www` folder first before sync. Thus I use the

```
ionic build
```

Command, to build all the files into www and run

```
npx cap sync 
npx cap open android
```

Tada, android project is updated.

Comment: you don't have to do all of that... there is one command to handle it - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61193773/122313

Answer (score 3):

Every time you perform a build (e.g. ionic build) that changes your web directory (default: www), you'll need to copy those changes down to your native projects:

1. ionic build or npm run build
2. npx cap copy
3. npx cap open android

reference : https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/getting-started/with-ionic

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the ionic commands the all you have to do is call `ionic capacitor sync`... it will do all of the building and the copying of assets

https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/capacitor-sync